# Ввод через консоль playground xcode8

Tags: xcode, swift

Здравствуйте! 
Изучаю swift (3.0). Очень удобно это делать в playground. Но хочется делать ввод из плейграундовской консоли. Как это сделать?

Comment: Объясните подробнее, что вы хотите - в плейграунде есть консоль и в нее выводится все, что вы пишете.

Comment: аааа, 'ввод', я прочитал 'вывод'

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `readLine` из стандартной библиотеки Swift

Например:

```
let response = readLine(stripNewline: true)
```

`response` будет типа `String?` и будет содержать введенный текст

Comment: Большое спасибо! Может это особенность именно плейграунда (в отличии, например, от отдельного консольного приложения), но такая строчка не вызывает в консоли приглашения на ввод

Comment: Попробуйте установить ручной запуск в плейграунде

Comment: попробовал. Результат такой же. readline возвращает nil и программа идет выполняться дальше по строкам кода